# Unable to send keys in python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, bots

I am on a shopify site (https://lab401.com/) trying to build a checkout bot, the problem I am having is when I reach the stage to enter my card details, it is giving me this error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable
```

My code is:

```
        driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/main/div/form/div[1]/div/div[1]/section[1]/div/fieldset/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/iframe"))
        driver.find_element_by_id('number').send_keys('7777')#card number
        driver.find_element_by_id('number').send_keys('7777')#card number
        driver.find_element_by_id('number').send_keys('7777')#card number
        driver.find_element_by_id('number').send_keys('7777')#card number
        #######################################
        #Every Thing above this line works
        #######################################
        driver.find_element_by_id('name').send_keys('Mr John Doe')#name (problem starts here)
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/form/input[5]').send_keys('1029')#exp date
        driver.switch_to.default_content()
```

I am unsure why this is happening. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Each of those fields are in another iframe. Simply switch to the others.

```
(//iframe[@class='card-fields-iframe'])[1]
(//iframe[@class='card-fields-iframe'])[2]
```